# Django Rest Framework for commercial use

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The question is: can I use Django Rest Framework for commercial use? The reason why I'm asking this is because in their [website](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#funding), they talk about "signing up for a paid plan".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IANAL but the license is all that matters:

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are **permitted** provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. **Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation** and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

That said, they are strongly encouraging you sign-up for a plan to support development efforts. That doesn't mean you *have* to sign-up, but it will help the project. Open-source developers need to eat too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would like to get the pay plan, but by the moment I'm only a student and have no money. Probably in the future I will get subscribed